# main page of Codeigniter not found

Tags: codeigniter

I have a problem with my CI project in my linux server (there is no problem in windows wamp),
in my project every route works fine except main page (address http://example.com without any query string), that shows 404 error.
here my configs : 
htaccess :

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 
Options -Indexes
php_flag output_buffering On
```

my routes.php :

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'index';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['index'] = 'index/index';
$route['/'] = 'index/index'; // i have controller index.php and action index for first page that load with address example.com/index/index
```

my config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO'; //and  "REQUEST_URI" both tested.
```

any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

This problem of "it works on Windows but not on Linux" is almost always due to incorrect file naming. It appears your 'default_controller' class is named "index". Both the file name and the class declaration MUST use an uppercase first character.

In other words, the file must be **Index.php** (note the uppercase **I**) and the declaration must be

```
class Index extends CI_Controller
```

Again, note the uppercase "I" in Index.

All that said, [CodeIgniter documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/reserved_names.html#controller-names) clearly states that a controller should **NOT** be named **Index**. **So, pick some other name**.